# Mapping with EF Core enumeration property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have class Person which has property CardType

```
public class Person{
    protected Person(){}    
    public Person(CardType cardType){
       cardType = CardType;
    }

    public CardType CardType { get; private set; }
    ... other properties ommited
}



public class CardType : Enumeration
{
    public static CardType Amex = new CardType(1, "Amex");
    public static CardType Visa = new CardType(2, "Visa");
    public static CardType MasterCard = new CardType(3, "MasterCard");

    public CardType(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map CardType property using EF Core

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
{
   builder.ToTable("Person");
   builder.Property(x => x.CardType);
}
```

But I'm getting following:

> The property 'Person.CardType' is of type 'CardType' which is not
>   supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR
>   type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by
>   using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Does database model have a table CardType?  Mapping model does not have CardType so exception says to add property NotMapped.

Comment: it doesn't have a table CardType, it should live under Person table inside CardType column

Comment: You can make CardType owned type or use value conversion.

Comment: How can you have a database table inside a database column?

Comment: @jdweng please read again, it's CardType column under Person table.

Comment: The make is an enumeration (which defaults to int) and not a class.  Your CardType is three different properties. public enum CardType { Amex = 1, Visa = 2, MasterCard = 3} The enumeration string value will give the enumeration name.  You can also use Parse method to get int from string.  Or you can cast an int to the enumeration int cardValue = 2;  CardType card = (CardType)cardValue;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use custom classes as types for Data properties (they can be used in navigation properties only). You need to use enum:

```
public enum CardType
{
    Default = 0,
    Amex,
    Visa,
    MasterCard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store only an ID of Enumeration object in the db, also make use of HasConversion method to convert your enumeration type back and forth like this

```
builder.Property(c => c.CardType).HasConversion(c => c.Id, c => CardType.From(c));
```

Where "From" method can instantiate an Enumeration from provided Id